# Is the "before" used correctly in sentence "I have never been there before"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to tell someone that I've never been there, so I say:

> I have never been there before.

Is it correct? I've a concern that the sentence is not complete and we need to add something after *before*.

1. I have never been there before today.
2. I have never been there before now.

Or is there any better way to express it with the word *before*?

---

Update:

Thanks for all answers, and I have an additional related question.

If I don't use *never*, is it correct with the *before* at the end? For example:

> I haven't been there before.

Comment: See: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138524/quotes for an amusing use of this construction (which takes some parsing, though you could listen to a clip instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence is fine as it is. *Before* can be used as an adverb (or as some grammarians call it, a prepositional adverb).

Comment: Can I say `I haven't been there before` without the word `never`?

Comment: Sure, that's fine too.

Answer (score 3):

The use of "today" or "now" is unnecessary in the sentence. When you use the adverb "never", it means " not at any time/not in your whole life up to the present". So your original sentence "I have never been there before" is natural and makes full sense.

Even you don't use "before", the sentence will convey the same meaning but with a subtle difference. You are  using "before" to indicate or emphasize  that you have never been there and it's for the first time you are going to visit the place.

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence sounds fine as is; it doesn't make any sense to actually add "today" or "now" to complete the sentence, because "before" basically does the job.

However, if you would like to use the word "today", then you would probably decide to say:

> I haven't been there today. [Excluding the *never*]
>
> I haven't been there yesterday.

Regardless of what you decide to choose or say, you can say it without being specific on when you've been there like you don't have to emphasis on what you want to say or convey to the person your talking you by adding words such as "today" with "before" ((just like what you're inquiring about))

Comment: But note that this means specifically "today". You might have been there yesterday or earlier.